# Malformed Manifest - Tag <activity> missing required attribute name

Tags: java, android

I keep getting the Tag *activity* missing required attribute name, Tag *action* missing required attribute name, and Tag *category* missing required attribute name errors when attempting to run my app. Manifest file follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.caom/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cobyllamarco.morsoul"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:name=".MorsoulDemo0"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Morsoul Demo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MorsoulDemo0"
            android:label="Morsoul Demo0"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I combed through to set all packages to lower case and sent it through an XML validator online(came back valid). Help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in namespace.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.caom/apk/res/android"
```

There should be `com`, not `caom`.

I've tried to make this typo and get the same result: "missed 'name' attribute".

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I kind of feel dumb not catching THAT, but still, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your application & activity tags seem to have same attribute 'name=.MorsoulDemo0'. **Only give an Application subclass as name attribute of application tag & give an Activity as name attribute of activity tag**.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'm still having an issue with the activity name when changed to `<activity
            android:name=".activity_morsoul_demo0"
            android:label="Morsoul Demo0"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >` And I have no idea why action and category are still registering as not having a name... But, again, I thank you for you're time in answering this.

Comment: Is "activity_morsoul_demo0" an xml layout or java class ??

Comment: Use your Activity class name in android:name attribute, NOT your layout file name.

Comment: That does help too. Thanks!